# How do I show full information when I click on a list item?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recyclerview that shows the image and first name and phone number, how do I implement that when you click on the item opens detailed information about the contact (picture, first name, last name, number, email, notes)

My adapter

```
class ContactsAdapter (private val context: Context, private val mContactsList: ArrayList<Contacts> = ArrayList())
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    fun setupContacts(contactsList: ArrayList<Contacts>) {
        mContactsList.clear()
        mContactsList.addAll(contactsList)
        //search(query = "")
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_contact, parent, false)
        return ContactsViewHolder(itemView = itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mContactsList.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is ContactsViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(contactsModel = mContactsList[position])
        }
    }

    class ContactsViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mContactIcon: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image)
        var mContactFirstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_first_name)
        var mContactPhone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone)
        //var mContactLastName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_last_name)

        fun bind(contactsModel: Contacts) {
            contactsModel.images?.let { url ->
                Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
                    .into(mContactIcon)
            }

            mContactFirstName.text = contactsModel.firstName
            mContactPhone.text = contactsModel.phone
        }
    }
}
```

My Model class

```
data class Contacts(

    @SerializedName("firstName")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    val lastName: String,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @SerializedName("notes")
    val notes: String,
    @SerializedName("images")
    val images: String?
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add an answer with a General example, maybe someone will need it. For correct operation, make sure that your "Model" class implements the Serializable or Parcelable interface (the second one seems to work faster). The Class Model:

```
data class Contacts(
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    val firstName: String,
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    val lastName: String,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @SerializedName("notes")
    val notes: String,
    @SerializedName("images")
    val images: String?
) : Serializable
```

Adapter:

```
class ContactsAdapter (private val context: Context, private val mContactsList: ArrayList<Contacts> = ArrayList())
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    fun setupContacts(contactsList: ArrayList<Contacts>) {
        mContactsList.clear()
        mContactsList.addAll(contactsList)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val itemView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_contact, parent, false)
        return ContactsViewHolder(itemView = itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mContactsList.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (holder is ContactsViewHolder) {
            holder.bind(contactsModel = mContactsList[position])

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    val contactsModel: Contacts = mContactsList[position]
                    val intent = Intent(context, DetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("contact", contactsModel)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION
                    context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    class ContactsViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var mContactIcon: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image)
        var mContactFirstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_first_name)
        var mContactPhone: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone)

        fun bind(contactsModel: Contacts) {
            contactsModel.images?.let { url ->
                Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_placeholder)
                    .into(mContactIcon)
            }
            mContactFirstName.text = contactsModel.firstName
            mContactPhone.text = contactsModel.phone
        }
    }
}
```

The second (receiving) Activity:

```
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "DetailsActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

        val clickedContact: Contacts = intent.getSerializableExtra("contact") as Contacts

        details_first_name.text = clickedContact.firstName
        details_last_name.text = clickedContact.lastName
        details_phone.text = clickedContact.phone
        details_email.text = clickedContact.email
        details_notes.text = clickedContact.notes

        Picasso.with(this@DetailsActivity).load(clickedContact.images).into(details_image)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set the onClickListener inside the `bind()` method

```
fun bind(contactsModel: Contacts) {
     itemView.setOnClickListener { showMoreInfo(contactsModel) }
...
}
```

cause views are recycled, the current model will be passed to `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

For expanded recycler view  you can follow like this.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical">
<View
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:id="@+id/item_divider" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    tools:text="Léon: The Professional" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sub_item"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_item_genre"
        tools:text="Genre:  Crime, Drama, Thriller" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_item_year"
        tools:text="Year: 1993" />
</LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Adapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = list.get(position);
    // Set movie data
    holder.bind(movie);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // Get the current state of the item
        boolean expanded = movie.isExpanded();
        // Change the state
        movie.setExpanded(!expanded);
        // Notify the adapter that item has changed
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    });
}

// Method in ViewHolder class
private void bind(Movie movie) {
    // Get the state
    boolean expanded = movie.isExpanded();
    // Set the visibility based on state
    subItem.setVisibility(expanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    genre.setText("Genre: " + movie.getGenre());
    year.setText("Year: " + movie.getYear());
}
```

Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    movieList = setupList();

    RecAdapter adapter = new RecAdapter(movieList);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recview);

    // Removes blinks
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    // Standard setup
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}
```